# selenium exceptions.NoSuchElementException:

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The html code snippet as:

```
<thead id="addDet:cust:th" class="emp">
<tr id="addDet:cust:ch" class="emp">
<th class="emp" scope="col" id="addDet:cust:ch:j_idt484">S. No.</th>
<th class="emp" scope="col" id="addDet:cust:ch:j_idt487">Name 
<font color="#FA5882">*</font></th>
```

I tried to fill the field as:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("addDet:cust:j_idt487").send_keys("XX")
```

But I am getting the error as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"psdetail:j_idt490"}
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I am afraid, I don't see any `<input>` tag of type `text` or `textarea` where you can type in the data "XX". Can you please attach a screenshot of the element you want to type-in data into? It will then be easier to comprehend what you are inferring.

Comment: Its in the indian railways ticket booking site, and the page is of filling up the passenger details after selecting the train.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath you've provided **doesn't point to a field to input data into, in fact it's actually pointing to the column header**. That's why you weren't able to input data into it.

Please try the below xpath to **fill the name and age in the first row** in the passenger details:

1. The below code will fill the **name of passenger** in first row:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tbody[@id='addPassengerForm:psdetail:tb']//input[contains(@id,'psgnName')])[1]").send_keys("ABC")
```

2. The below code will fill the **age of passenger** in first row:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//tbody[@id='addPassengerForm:psdetail:tb']//input[contains(@id,'psgnAge')])[1]").send_keys("24")
```

Similarly for inputting data into the next row for passenger name, you just have to tweak the last part of xpath from **`[1]` to `[2]`**.

Comment: Now working for assigning the date of journey ! anyways, Cheers :)

Comment: Godspeed @user2336944.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code.  You forgot the `:ch:` after `:cust:`.

Comment: Still the same
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"addDet:cust:ch:j_idt490"}

Comment: Why did it change to jdt490 this time?

Comment: Is find_element_by_id a method you wrote yourself?  If so, can you post the code for that really fast?

Comment: It's a method of selenium package in python and differs from the one in java.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your selector (Imcphers answer/comments), is it possible that the element is NOT in the DOM at the time you're trying to find the element?  Is it dynamically loaded?  If so you'll probably have to use an `explicit` or `implicit` wait.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Try
`driver.implicitly_wait(10)`
after you initialize your driver

Comment: The page is dynamically loaded and its the text box after the form gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try using xpath contains or CSS start with
//xpath
"//*[contains(. , 'S. No.')]"

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute value looks very much like it is *dynamically generated*. In this case it is not a good idea to rely on it. Instead, use the element's text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[. = 'S. No.']")
```

Comment: Yes, the page is dynamically generated, I tried the one but no help.

Comment: @user2336944 do you have any `iframe` elements on the page?

Comment: @user2336944 can you share the actual link to the website?

Comment: www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf

Comment: and there is no iframe elements.

Comment: @user2336944 thanks, but I don't see the HTML you've presented inside the page HTML...

Comment: that's the page comes after successful login and selecting the source and destinations, selecting the train from the list.